# Problem in showing additional field of pivot table in Larvel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am using Laravel Nova for my admin side.
I have this problem that in my pivot table, I added additional field.
I have user table and event table. User can have many event, and event can have many users. So I created a pivot table for the 2 models. But I want to the status of the event of user. So I added additional field for status in pivot table.

My problem now is in the Laravel Nova.
In my event resource, I have this:

```
BelongsToMany::make('Pending Users', 'pendingUsers', 'App\Nova\User'),
```

It shows another table for pending clients. I can already get the list of users in specific event but I can't show to the table the status of the event of user. If the user is approved or still pending.

What strategy is best in my case? I am thinking to make a model for Event and User.

I don't know how to show the additional field of pivot table in BelongsToMany in Laravel Nova. It just shows what I added in User Resource of Nova. Like ID and name. But I don't know where the status of user's event will show. I want to show it in the table of BelongsToMany of events to users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that you're defining the relationship in BOTH models, and then letting Nova know which fields you want to show like this:

In your event resource:

```
BelongsToMany::make('Users')
->fields(function() {
    return [
        Text::make('status')
    ];
}),
```

In your event model:

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('status');
}
```

In your user model:

```
public function events()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class)->withPivot('status');
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Is there a way to show the File to index so that the user can download it and doesn't need to add action for download.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by defining `->withPivot('filed name)'` on the relationship it drove me insane for a long time.

```
BelongsToMany::make('your_relationship')
    ->fields(function () {
        return [
            Text::make('your_text'),
        ];
    })
```

Your relation will be here something just like this what i said previous

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('filed name');
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? I already have this:
 return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('proof_of_payment');
But the table for pending users in my event still shows the full name of the user only.

Comment: BelongsToMany::make('Pending Users', 'pendingUsers', 'App\Nova\Users'),

Comment: I can now get the data of additional column in pivot table. But it will just show once I click "edit" of belongsToMany. Like for example, I have a column in pivot table for proof_of_payment - It will just show if I click the edit. It is not downloadable.

Comment: I am sorry that I answer not on time)) I see it just working. It worked with pivot adding to your model. I hope that my help was helpful for youy!!